# How to clear the WorkStatus create by WorkManager in Android?

Tags: android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-workmanager

I create some `OneTimeWorkRequest` When I use the android-arch work WorkManager.
I can watch `WorkStatus` by observer like this

```
final WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
final LiveData<List<WorkStatus>> workStatus =
    workManager.getStatusesByTag(DailyWorker.DAILY_WORK);
observer = new Observer<List<WorkStatus>>() {
  @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable List<WorkStatus> workStatuses) {
    Log.d("WorkManager", "onChanged  = workStatuses = " + workStatuses);
    if (workStatuses == null || workStatuses.size() == 0) {
      //DailyWorker.createNewPeriodWork();
    } else {
      Log.d("WorkManager ", "onChanged  = workStatuses.size() = " + workStatuses.size());
      for (int i = 0; i < workStatuses.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("WorkManager ", "onChanged Work Status Id: " + workStatuses.get(i).getId());
        Log.d("WorkManager ", "onChanged Work Status State: " + workStatuses.get(i).getState());
      }
    }
    workStatus.removeObserver(observer);
  }
};
workStatus.observe(this, observer);
```

My Android arch version is `android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha02`

But there are a lot of `WorkStatus` in the list，some `SUCCEEDED` ,some `ENQUEUED` , some `CANCELLED`, and the number of the list continue increase.
how can I clear the WorkStatus List?

Answer (score 20):

You can call the method `pruneWork()` on your WorkManager to clear the `List<WorkStatus>`.

```
myWorkManager.pruneWork();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I wish it had a method like "pruneWorkByTag" to clear only specific groups of tasks...

Answer (score 0):

You can call WorkRequest#keepResultsForAtLeast when you make the work